# Find Closed End Formula for Recurrence equation by master theorem

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, asymptotic-complexity, master-theorem

Can we solve this 
     **`T(n) = 2T( n/2 ) + n lg n`** recurrence equation master theorem I am coming from a link where he is stating that  we can't apply here master theorem because it doesn't satisfied any of the 3ree case condition. On the other hand he has taken a another example 
**`T(n) = 27T(n/3) + Θ(n^3 lg n)`**  and find the closed solution **`theta(n^3logn)`**  For solving this he used 2nd case of master theorem **`If f(n) = Θ(nlogba (lg n)k ) then T(n) ∈ Θ(nlogba (lg n)k+1) for some k >= 0`**  Here my confusion arises why not we can apply 2nd case here while it is completely fit in 2nd case. 
**My thought:**  a = 2 , b =2; let k =1 then 
  f(n) = theta(n^log_2 2 logn) for k= 1 so T(n) = theta(nlogn) But he as mentioned on this we can't apply master theorem I m confused why not.

Note: It is due to f(n) bcz in **`T(n) = 2T( n/2 ) + n lg n`** `f(n) = nlog n` and in  **`T(n) = 27T(n/3) + Θ(n^3 lg n)`** **`f(n) = theta(n^3log n)`**  Please Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Sorry I was forget to mention here is link http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C455/html/notes/Chapter4/CookbookMethod.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using case 2 of master theorem I find that

```
 T(n) = Theta( n log^2 (n))
```

Your link states that the case 2 of theroem is :

```
 f(n) = Theta( n log_b(a))
```

While from several other links, like the [one from mit](http://people.csail.mit.edu/thies/6.046-web/master.pdf), the case is :

```
 f(n) = Theta( n log_b(a) log_k(n)) for k >= 0
```

Comment: Actually for case (2) he has assumed k = 0  later he has mentioned in same link for solving T(n) = 27T(n/3) + Θ(n^3 lg n) this equation

Comment: at the top of this page, he use the same link the one i provided. look it up, there is the solution